# SQL Выборка из двух таблиц где значения второй таблицы записаны в результирующий массив под определенным ключем

Tags: sql

Вроде простой вопрос но почему то не получается найти решение.

Есть две таблицы. 
Например `users` и их `comments`.

```
users:
id = 111

comments:
id = 111111
user_id = 111
comment = text comment


id = 222222
user_id = 111
comment = text comment
```

Как сделать `sql` запрос чтобы выбрать юзера с его комментариями вот так:
(в массив `user` подставить массив `comments` **с заданным ключем `comments`**

```
    Array (
       [id] => 111
       [comments] => array (
                       [0] => Array (
                              [id] = 22222
                              [user_id] = 111
                              [comment] = text comment
                             ) 
                       [1] => Array (
                              [id] = 22222
                              [user_id] = 111
                              [comment] = text comment
                             )
       )
    )
```

Comment: *Есть две таблицы. Например users и их comments.* Замените эту непонятную фигню на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скрипты. *запрос чтобы выбрать юзера с его комментариями вот так* - Вот именно так? что-то оно выглядит как вывод массива в дамп из пэхапэ, а ни разу не как результат выполнения запроса.

Comment: Самый простой пример. Проще не придумать. связь один ко многим. у юзера есть комментарии. хочу вывести одним запросом юзеров с их комментами но в нормальном формате чтобы в результирующем массиве у каждого юзера по ключю comments можно было его комменты получать.
Я понимаю что можно 2 запроса сделать и перебрать массивы в такой формат, но неужели нельзя это сделать средствами sql?

Comment: 1) Результирующий набор, получаемый как результат выполнения SQL-запроса - это ВСЕГДА прямоугольная таблица. И НИКОГДА - иерархический список или дерево. 2) Постарайтесь научиться различать получение данных и их отрисовку на экране. Внешне они могут быть весьма слабопохожи. 3) *Я понимаю что можно 2 запроса сделать и перебрать массивы в такой формат* - один запрос, а потом, если нужен именно такой формат, преобразование полученного плоского набора.

Comment: В общем понятно. средствами sql не получится такую выборку сделать( придется делать два запроса и потом уже собирать в нужный массив.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Любая выборка это результирующий набор умножения таблиц.
то есть 
select userid, comment from user, comments то есть таблица с заполненными данными, ели вы хотите получить все комментарии в одной записи то это возможно.

```
    SELECT
        comments.userId     
        , (SELECT 
                'comment: ' + comments1.text + '|' AS [text()] 
            FROM comments AS comments1
            WHERE 
                comments1.userId = comment.userId
            FOR XML PATH ('')) allComments
    FROM 
        comments
    GROUP BY 
        comments.userId
```

Далее Вы должны удалить последний разделитель и разделить в коде Ваши комментарии.